# Promise .then not waiting for response to save

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am first sending a POST request to add a new position to table ORDER, and after that promise is completed it then sends a post request to a table ORDER_PRODUCT to associate the previous order with some products. The thing is, it happens too fast, despite .then usage, response isnt  saved to const before second post fires

If i split those two post requests and fire them up manually then its all good.

```js
const orderHandler = () => {
  setError('')

  token
    ? axios
        .post(
          'http://localhost:8000/order/',
          {
            notes: notes,
            price: quantPrice,
            city: city,
            street: street,
            zipcode: zipcode,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Token ' + token,
            },
          },
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.id, 'wielki chuj')
          setOrderid(response.data.id)
        })
        //.then((response)=>setOrderid(response.data.id ))
        .then(() => console.log(orderid))
        .then(() => {
          cartItems.map((j) =>
            axios.post(
              'http://localhost:8000/orderproduct/',
              {
                order: orderid,
                product: j.id,
                quantity: j.quant,
              },
              {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: 'Token ' + token,
                },
              },
            ),
          )
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data.body)
          setError(error.response.data.body)
        })
    : setError('You must be logged in')
}
```

Comment: you should use the order id directly from the response of the first request

Comment: ^this saved me. Thank you @subparry i was already deep into trying to force setState to return a promise and didnt think of something this simple

Answer (score 0):

the answer was to pass response.data to second POST directly, and not through state. This was suggested by subparry.

```
.then((response) => {
        cartItems.map((j) =>
          axios.post(
            'http://localhost:........
```